# Get First value of array in projection, array which is created using $addToSet mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is their any way to get only the first element of the array, array is created in $group pipeline of aggregation using $addToSet

My aggregation query is as follow :

```
db.event.aggregate([
{
$group:
    {
        _id:{"City":"$TracInfo.City"},
        "EventCount":{"$sum":1},
        "Latitude":{"$addToSet":"$TracInfo.Longitude"},
        "Longitude":{"$addToSet":"$TracInfo.Latitude"}
    } 
},
{
$project:
    {
        "_id":"$_id.City",
        "EventCount":"$EventCount",
        "Latitude":"$Latitude",
        "Longitude":"$Longitude"
    }
}]).pretty()
```

Here for Latitude, Longitude i get an array. I just want a single value from each to display city on geo map.

I tried $max on $Latitude and $Longitude.

error: "exception: invalid operator '$max'",
I even tried pop

```
"Latitude":{"$pop":{"$Latitude":-1}}
```

error: "exception: invalid operator '$pop'"

Thank you !! In Advance

Comment: What does first mean? Presumably you expect this to be sorted but `$addToSet` does not order the results. So we are going to have to sort it. But by what? And is "first" intended to the be "highest" or the "lowest" of these values?

Comment: i mean the first value of array, not specifically first i need but i need only a single value from the array as for now its returning me an array in projection, i need any single value from that array it can be first value of that array or last max any thing. For getting a specific answer i have mentioned 1st value of array (array Latitude and Longitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the order or value that you're going to get, you should use [$first](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator. It will return the first value matched in the `group` operation.

```
$group:
    {
        _id:{"City":"$TracInfo.City"},
        "EventCount":{"$sum":1},
        "Latitude":{"$first":"$TracInfo.Longitude"},
        "Longitude":{"$first":"$TracInfo.Latitude"}
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you! So now theirs no need to make an array for it and try to find one from it.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to **`$unwind`** the arrays before doing anything such as getting the first item. But the other problem here is that **`$addToSet`** does not maintain the order of results, so the first item is not necessarily the "highest" or "lowest" and you will need to **`$sort`** as well:

Or just using **`$first`**:

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$TracInfo.City"
        "EventCount":{"$sum":1},
        "Latitude":{"$addToSet":"$TracInfo.Longitude"},
        "Longitude":{"$addToSet":"$TracInfo.Latitude"}
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$Longitude" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "EventCount":{"$first": "$EventCount"},
        "Latitude":{ "$first": "$Latitude" },
        "Longitude":{ "$first": "$Longtitude" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$Latitude" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "EventCount":{"$first": "$EventCount"},
        "Latitude":{ "$first": "$Latitude" },
        "Longitude":{ "$first": "$Longtitude" }
    }}
])
```

Which gets you the results after you have reduced to a "set".

Or ordered:

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$TracInfo.City"
        "EventCount":{"$sum":1},
        "Latitude":{"$addToSet":"$TracInfo.Longitude"},
        "Longitude":{"$addToSet":"$TracInfo.Latitude"}
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$Longitude" },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "Longtitude": 1 },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "EventCount":{"$first": "$EventCount"},
        "Latitude":{ "$first": "$Latitude" },
        "Longitude":{ "$first": "$Longtitude" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$Latitude" },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "Latitude": 1 },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "EventCount":{"$first": "$EventCount"},
        "Latitude":{ "$first": "$Latitude" },
        "Longitude":{ "$first": "$Longtitude" }
    }}
])
```

I also presume you meant to swap the values of those fields.

Comment: Thank you!! your answer is exactly perfect for the aggregation query i had